# Qual o nome das pequenas partes de madeira que saem de um lápis quando é apontado?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Navegando pelo [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), site irmão deste aqui na StackExchange, porém voltado ao aprendizado da língua inglesa, cheguei a [esta pergunta](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344455/what-is-the-thin-flat-piece-of-wood-that-you-have-when-you-sharpen-your-pencil-c), interessantísima.

Nela é questionado qual o nome dos pequenos pedaços de madeira que saem de um lápis ao ser apontado, conforme pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

[image]

Um comentário argumenta que a resposta poderia ser obtida facilmente ao consultar um dicionário bilíngüe ou tradutor online ao pesquisar pelo nome no idioma original do perguntante. Neste momento me dei conta que, em décadas falando nativamente o Português (e uma parte desse tempo também apontando lápis), eu não sei como se chamam estes pequenos pedaços de madeira que saem de um lápis ao ser apontado.

Comment: em com reservatório para lascas [shavings] e também fecha por completo, não deixando sujeira cair onde você for deixar ele guardado. https://maarinices.com.br/produtos/apontador-de-lapis/ Acho que lasquinhas seria melhor, né

Comment: Acho que Lambie está mais correto para o uso comum, pois, é o que ouço e digo. Porém, encontrei [*apara*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/apara), que é são as sobras de uma aparação. A palavra *sobra* e sinônimos também funcionam.

Comment: @Schilive _Apara_ me pareceu um termo natural, de fácil entendimento. Quer transformar seu comentário em uma resposta para que eu possa aceitá-la?

Comment: @Lambie _Lasca_ me dá a impressão de um pedaço maior. Uma "lasca de madeira" seria, no meu entendimento (Sul do BR) um pedaço maior de madeira, como um que é usado para acender uma fogueira.

Comment: Foi por isso que disse lasquinhas. Lascas pequenas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usamos *apara* em português europeu [(1)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/apara), também atestado no Dicionário Michaelis [(2)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/palavra/7LQz/apara-2/).

Comment: "Apara" também faz sentido para brasileiros, embora eu não tenha certeza de qual é a palavra mais comum para isso.